# Haskell: Common Corecursive Fallacies

Tags: haskell, graph, graph-algorithm

So I was thinking about a graph distance algorithm tonight, and came up with this
while I was driving in the car:

```
module GraphDistance where
import Data.Map

distance :: (Ord a) => a -> Map a [a] -> Map a Int
distance a m = m' 
  where m' = mapWithKey d m
        d a' as = if a == a' then 0 else 1 + minimum (Prelude.map (m'!) as)
```

At first, I was fairly proud of myself, since it seemed so elegant.
But then I realized it wouldn't work - the corecursion might get stuck
in a loop.

I had to code it up to convince myself:

```
ghci> distance 1 $ fromList [(0,[1]),(1,[0,2]),(2,[1,3]),(3,[2])]
fromList [(0,1),(1,0),(2,^CInterrupted.
```

But now I think I've pretty much thought it through.

Is there a list of common errors and anti-patterns
when dealing with corecursive data that I can go read up on,
so I can train my brain to think corecursively?  Experience
has trained me fairly well for thinking through non-corecursive
data, but I'd like to learn from others mistakes if I can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there's really only one fundamental mistake when dealing with corecursive data, and that's carelessly using recursion on it!

Corecursion implies that data is being generated incrementally in some sense. Your graph distance function is instructive here, because it seems like it *should* work, so think about where the incremental part should be: The starting point is a distance of 0 from a node to itself, otherwise one greater than the minimum distance among its own immediate neighbors. Thus, we would expect *each distance value* to be incremental, which means we need them to be suitably corecursive themselves.

The recursion at issue, then, is occurring due to the combination of `(+)` and `minimum`: when finding the minimum, `1` will always be less than `1 + n`, without needing to worry about what `n` is... but there's no way to compare `Int`s without computing the entire value.

In short, the algorithm expects to be able to compare how many times `(1 +)` was applied to `0` only as far as needed; that is to say, it wants lazy natural numbers defined using "zero" and "successor".

Behold:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

natToInt :: Nat -> Int
natToInt Z = 0
natToInt (S n) = 1 + natToInt n

instance Show Nat where show = show . natToInt

instance Eq Nat where
    Z == Z = True
    (S n1) == (S n2) = n1 == n2
    _ == _ = False

    Z /= Z = False
    (S n1) /= (S n2) = n1 /= n2
    _ /= _ = True


instance Ord Nat where
    compare Z Z = EQ
    compare Z (S _) = LT
    compare (S _) Z = GT
    compare (S n1) (S n2) = compare n1 n2
```

And then in GHCi:

```
> distance 1 $ fromList [(0,[1]),(1,[0,2]),(2,[1,3]),(3,[2])]
fromList [(0,1),(1,0),(2,1),(3,2)]
```

Proof that your algorithm works<sup>[0]</sup>; your implementation of it was just incorrect.

---

Now, as a slight variation, let's apply your algorithm to a different graph:

```
> distance 1 $ fromList [(0,[1]),(1,[0]),(2,[3]),(3,[2])]
```

...what do we expect this to do? What is the distance from node 1 for nodes 2 or 3?

Running it in GHCi has the obvious result:

```
fromList [(0,1),(1,0),(2,^CInterrupted.
```

Nevertheless, *the algorithm works correctly on this graph*. Can you see the problem? Why did it hang in GHCi?

---

In summary, you need to clearly distinguish between two forms that can't be mixed freely:

- Lazy, possibly infinite data, generated corecursively
- Finite data, consumed recursively

Both forms can be transformed in a structure-agnostic way (e.g., `map` works on finite and infinite lists both). Codata can be consumed incrementally, driven by a corecursive algorithm; data can be generated recursively, limited by a recursive algorithm.

What you *can't* do is consume codata recursively (e.g., left folding an infinite list) or generate data corecursively (rare in Haskell, due to laziness).

**[0]**: Actually, it will fail on some inputs (e.g., some disconnected graphs), but that's a different issue.

Comment: So [I tried to use a lazy integer type](https://gist.github.com/1014374) , but I got the same behaviour as before (hanging).  Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @rampion: At a glance, I'd say it's probably being too strict somewhere when examining the lazy integer values, which is likely to be unavoidable. This actually has the same conceptual problem as using `Int`, it just makes the problem less obvious. Comparing values needs the sign, and the sign needs the entire computation due to subtraction. It may still be possible, but you'd have to be very careful about the operations not forcing more than they actually need.